# How to type star (*) into command line in Far Manager?

Tags: windows, far-manager

I'm typing into command line in Far Manager and need `*` character there. But when I press <kbd>*</kbd> key Far Manager executes associated command which is "select all" in active panel.

For example, I'm creating backups like this:

```
copy C:\*.txt C:\*.bak
```

Comment: Are you on a laptop?

Comment: Nope, standard PC and keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LAlt + 42
```

This shortcut is for `*` character in [Windows environment](http://www.webnots.com/alt-key-windows-shortcuts/). It differs from pressing actual key on numeric keyboard because OS does not interpret it as key press I guess. Thus Far Manager does not take it as command and types `*` into command line as wanted.

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with the question. If it does, you need to explain better.

Comment: This shortcut is for star (*) character in Windows environment ([http://www.webnots.com/alt-key-windows-shortcuts/](http://www.webnots.com/alt-key-windows-shortcuts/)). It differs from pressing actual key on numeric keyboard because OS does not interpret it as key press I guess. Thus Far Manager does not take it as command and type * into command line as wanted.

Comment: @Andrew Please don't add extra information in the comments. Edit your answer and add it there (comments are not permanent and can be deleted at any time).

Answer (score 3):

Press Ctrl+O to toggle panels (hide in your case) and type whatever you want in command-line.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be answering the OP's question.

Comment: @Burgi Try yourself and you'll see that my solution works

Answer (score 1):

The `*` character can also be typed by keys in the alphanumeric part of most keyboard layouts, in which case it is not treated as a command either.

For instance, in the US layout it can be found on the <kbd>8</kbd> key, meaning you can type it as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> – an even shorter cut, if you ask me.

Comment: True but I do not use US layout and `*` is not located there. I found shortcut for my layout `RAlt + /` but did not mention it as shortcut above is layout-universal (at least for Windows) thus better solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You need a macro.
Here is ready-to-use one: `Addons\Macros\Panel.Numpad.lua`

Purpose:

- if command line if empty it <kbd>*</kbd> acts as 'select all'
- if command line is *not* empty <kbd>*</kbd> enters `*` symbol